# TRIM on OCZ RevoDrive 3 on CentOS

Tags: centos, ssd, trim

I've got an OCZ RevoDrive 3 mounted as / on my CentOS 6.3 box running kernel 2.6.32-220.17.1.el6.x86_64. /boot is on a HDD since OCZ's driver apparently doesn't yet support booting directly to it. While testing, the drive mounted with the 'discard' option just fine. It only seems to be disabling itself after mounting automatically via fstab.

The option shows up in `mount`:

```
[root@craft ocz]# mount
/dev/sdb3 on / type ext4 (rw,noatime,discard)
```

But /var/log/messages says:

> Aug 12 04:49:53 craft kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device sdb3): release_blocks_on_commit: discard not supported, disabling

I attempted to test if it was working anyways with `hdparm`, but an issue that I assume is unrelated to this one causes hdparm to segfault when trying to `--read-sectors`, so I'm not sure what else to check.

Anyone know how I could get discard working properly?

*Update*: /etc/fstab line for the partition in question, as requested in comments:

> UUID=a869cf38-7547-49a9-aeb5-17adb56b4bd4 / ext4    defaults,noatime,discard 1 2

Comment: Could you post your fstab line for /dev/sdb3?

Comment: @grs Done. I should've thought to do that in the first place!

Comment: Does `hdparm -I /dev/sdb | grep -i trim` have any output?

Comment: @Charles, Yup! Supported: `* Data Set Management TRIM supported` and `* Deterministic read after TRIM`